# Having tourble setting up aliases in zsh

Tags: command-line-interface, alias, zsh, zshrc

Hi I'm trying to set up an alias as a shortcut to go to specific directory in the cli. I'm running the following command:

```js
alias react=Documents/More/Reacting/News
```

after that I type react and it takes me to the correct location. However when I open a new tab this command no longer works.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you want this alias to *change* current directory to `Documents/More/Reacting/News` you should use `cd`:

```
alias react='cd Documents/More/Reacting/News'
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you must have the `AUTO_CD` option set in order for `cd`ing like this
to be working.  Nice.

Then, rather than setting an alias, you probably want to use
`CDABLE_VARS` to quickly jump around in this fashion.  Then you create
variables for your frequent dirs.  Your full use case then looks like:

```
% setopt cdablevars autocd
% fav1=~/some/common/place
% fav2=~/some/other/common/place
...
% fav1  # does a cd into ~/some/common/place
```

Your prompt may now even show a nice `~fav1` in it now!

These changes should go into your `~/.zshrc` in order to be persistent
across new shells (tabs as you're seeing them).

Find docs for these in the `zshbuiltins(1)` man page.